# How to select columns that exist in case classes from DataFrame

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, case-class

Given a spark DataFrame with columns `"id", "first", "last", "year"`

```
val df=sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, "John", "Doe", 1986),
  (2, "Ive", "Fish", 1990),
  (4, "John", "Wayne", 1995)
)).toDF("id", "first", "last", "year")
```

and case class

```
case class IdAndLastName(
id: Int,
last:String )
```

I would like to only select columns in case class which are `id` and `last`. In other words, I would like to have this output `df.select("id","last")` by using case class. I am avoiding hardcoding the attributes. Could you please help me how can I achieve this in a compact way.

Comment: So... lets say you are not hardcoding and somehow come up with a "generic" way of selecting columns from dataframe. Now how are you ever going to use that dataframe without knowing column names ?

Comment: This is post development and pre production. The less hardcoded values the more quality of the production. Any one can easily see the column names by looking at the case class as you can write it as `df.select(fieldnames.head, fieldnames.tail:_*).as[IdAndLastName]`

Comment: Are `id` and `last` in `case class IdAndLastName(id: Int, last:String)` not hardcoded ? This encoder hack for this case class will work only if the dataframe has explicit fields named `id` and `last`. This is no less hardcoded than just using the "id" and "last" column names in any way. This looks like an mis-interpretation or over generalization of the coding guideline which says "don't hardcode things, if possible". Here "hard-coding" does not just refer to "Strings" but its about tightly coupling two unrelated things, which might change and thus might require multiple changes in your code.

Comment: I think you are just thinking in scale of above example. Case class is getting used in many places in functions and objects, and 1) if there is a revision(add/remove/rename column), we don't want to go and edit each and every places 2) You already answered "The encoder for this case class will work only if the dataframe has explicit fields named id and last" We want to ensure the structure/schema of the data is the same everywhere, also if some operations/engineers are missing/using these attributes differently, let it fail. This is what we want.

Comment: 3) it is quite helpful to write test cases when you work with datasets. 4) with hardcoded value you will not catch the schema related errors in compile time, but you will be aware of the error in the run time, which might be costly ...

Comment: Your `df.select(fieldnames.head, fieldnames.tail:_*).as[IdAndLastName]` will also fail at run time only. But, yes later operations will be better as then you will be dealing with an strcutued dataframe. But this advantage will be there regardless of how your do this DataFrame casting. Anyways, there are tradeoffs to all approaches. `df.select("id", "last").as[IdAndLastName]` looks better to me, as it is more explicit and can be easily cross-checked in code reviews.

Comment: well, what to you think the result of `df.select("id", "first", "last").as[IdAndLastName]` would be? would fail? would it succeed, if succeed, which columns it will pick. that is the point.

Comment: Will depend on the encoder implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create explictly an encoder for the case class (usually this happens implicitly [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/c1f8d759a3d75885e694e8c468ee6beea70131a3/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLImplicits.scala#L251)). Then you can get the field names from the encoder and use them in the select statement:

```scala
val fieldnames = Encoders.product[IdAndLastName].schema.fieldNames
df.select(fieldnames.head, fieldnames.tail:_*).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+
| id| last|
+---+-----+
|  1|  Doe|
|  2| Fish|
|  4|Wayne|
+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val cols = Encoders.product[IdAndLastName].schema.fieldNames.map(col)
df.select(cols: _*).show()
```